# Take input from csv file

Tags: java

I have one java file containing static input code with one public class.

Now I want to take input from csv file.

How can I do that ?

Do I need to create new java file?

Comment: If you want the static input code java file to be there then keep it as it is else you can modify the file to accept both dynamic and static values.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at [apache csv](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)

it's a very useful lib for this